# Reference active sheet in another workbook

Tags: excel

I have a workbook (logging.xlsx) with one sheet per month. In this sheet I enter different numbers per month.

To visualize the information from the logging workbook, I want to use some charts in an external (reporting) workbook. I prefer to have these charts in an external workbook, as the format of the logging workbook is not totally under my control.

To grep information from the logging workbook I'd like to automatically sync the information into the reporting workbook. To do so I can use external references like `=[logging.xlsx]July!$I$1`, however, this requires to make one reporting sheet per sheet in the logging workbook which increases the maintenance work in the reporting workbook.

Hence I was wondering whether there is a way, instead of `=[logging.xlsx]July!$I$1` to use something like `=[logging.xlsx]*ACTIVE_SHEET*!$I$1`

Comment: Do you mean use the name of the currently active sheet to determine which sheet to look at in the other workbook?

Comment: No. The idea is basically to open both sheets in parallel and whichever sheet in the logging workbook is currently active is visualised. Alternatively it would also be ok for me that I have to specify the sheet in Logging.xlsx in a cell in the reporting sheet.

Comment: Your first suggestion is only possible through the use of VBA, your second suggestion can be achieved by using the `=INDIRECT()` function.

Comment: @MacroMan: The indirect function looks like a good solution. 
I generated two cells containing the workbook name (A1) and the worksheet name (B1) in a reference sheet. Then I added to D10 the formula =CONCATENATE("[";$A$1;"]";$B$1;"!D10")
And in a second sheet in D10 =INDIRECT(ref!D10)

The remaining problem is that excel doesnt update the D10 in the Concatenate function when I do copy paste to other cells. Any suggestions?
     

However, if I try to copy large ranges of the sheet this will get slightly cumbersome

Comment: Ok, I found the solution: =CONCATENATE("[";$A$1;"]";$B$1;"!";ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()))
Thanks for the help

Comment: Just posted that as an answer at the same time you commented! Great minds think alike I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

In D10 add the formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("[";$A$1;"]";$B$1;"!";ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))
```

In the second sheet use:

```
=INDIRECT(ref!D10)
```